# Changing a number to text

Tags: excel

I have a number in A1 which is 37.5 but it shows as 37.50

I want to copy this into cell B2, covert it to text and show 37.50 and then I can remove the . to only show 3750

How would I do this?

Reason I am doing this is because I am trying to use the formula =TEXT(A1,"00000000000") but because A1 is a number, it is showing as 00000000038. What I need it to show as is 00000003750. Thats why I want to convert A1 to a text field and remove the . so it will show correctly.

Comment: `=TEXT(A1*100,"00000000000")`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can remove the period using substitute, and then format it:

```
=TEXT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",""),"00000000000")
```

Comment: Hi Bajal, this is now showing it as 00000000375 but I need it to be 00000003750. The reason it is not adding a 0 at the end is because the cell A1 is actually 37.5, not 37.50

Comment: Ah, I see. In that case, you'll have to format the column A as "text". Alternately you can multiply by 100 and then do the text format -- assuming you are dealing with only two decimal places.

Comment: Yes, thanks, multiplying by 100 works. That was simple. Thanks for the help Bajal.

Answer (score -2):

Use kutools or Just right click and format cell

Comment: Just double-click in a cell and enter the apostrophe before the numeric value. Maybe this work?